# How can I run an EXE file from my C# code?

Tags: c#, .net

I have an EXE file reference in my C# project.  How do I invoke that EXE file from my code?

Answer (score 375, accepted):

```
using System.Diagnostics;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Process.Start("C:\\");
    }
}
```

If your application needs cmd arguments, use something like this:

```
using System.Diagnostics;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        LaunchCommandLineApp();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Launch the application with some options set.
    /// </summary>
    static void LaunchCommandLineApp()
    {
        // For the example
        const string ex1 = "C:\\";
        const string ex2 = "C:\\Dir";

        // Use ProcessStartInfo class
        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
        startInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
        startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        startInfo.FileName = "dcm2jpg.exe";
        startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        startInfo.Arguments = "-f j -o \"" + ex1 + "\" -z 1.0 -s y " + ex2;

        try
        {
            // Start the process with the info we specified.
            // Call WaitForExit and then the using statement will close.
            using (Process exeProcess = Process.Start(startInfo))
            {
                exeProcess.WaitForExit();
            }
        }
        catch
        {
             // Log error.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `startInfo.UseShellExecute = false` was an awesome thing...It worked for me like a charm! Thank you! :)

Comment: @logganB.lehman  process hangs forever on  exeProcess.WaitForExit(); any idea?

Answer (score 20):

Look at [Process.Start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e8zac0ca.aspx) and [Process.StartInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.startinfo.aspx)

Comment: Can you make your answer more comprehensive? And/or point to a duplicate?

Answer (score 20):

Example:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("mspaint.exe");
```

Compiling the Code

Copy the code and paste it into the **Main** method of a console application.
Replace "mspaint.exe" with the path to the application you want to run.

Comment: How does this provide more value than the already created answers? The accepted answer also shows the usage of `Process.Start()`

Comment: SO - it's OK to help a beginner with simplified, step by step examples with many details stripped away. Also ok to use caps :P

Comment: I just needed a quick way to execute the exe and this was really helpful. Thank you :)

Answer (score 10):

Example:

```
Process process = Process.Start(@"Data\myApp.exe")
int id = process.Id
Process tempProc = Process.GetProcessById(id)
this.Visible = false
tempProc.WaitForExit()
this.Visible = true
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create 2 executables: one is your main application and the other is an exe that will call your main application. The other exe will also be the one to update your main application.