# how to call exe in c# passing xml file as parameter to it

Tags: c#, xml, exe

I am developing c# application which will call exe file of saxonb9-1-0-8n and takes xml file as parameter in order to generate xslt file..do anybody have idea how to it or anybody have implemented this?/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9679375/run-an-exe-from-c-sharp-code

Answer (score 2):

Try it:

```
Process.Start("saxonb9-1-0-8n", "xmlFileName");
```

Comment: bt wer the result that is xslt file will b stored?

Comment: you can add parameter -o:output and set file where it must save

Answer (score 0):

You should look into the Process & ProcessStartInfo Class

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.aspx

```
string MyFileName = "saxonb9-1-0-8n.exe";
ProcessStartInfo proc = new ProcessStartInfo(MyFileName);
proc.Arguments = "xmlFileName";
Process.Start(proc);
```

Good Luck