# How I can activate an exe file with an installer, as an event?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, process

I have a `WindowsForm Application` and in `Form2` I have an `install button`. I want to do an event, when I make click on `install` to play the `executable file` who have the location here : `D:\Mat\R2008a\win64` and the name `setup.exe`. The extra condition is : I want this `exe` to play with `installer.ini` setup who is here :

```
string path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory.ToString();
 string installerfilename = path + "installer.ini";
```

I want to make my application like an installer.

I tried to use this code, but doesn't works:

```
private void Install_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
string desktopPath = @"D:\Mat\NSIS\R2008a\win64";
            ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
            psi.Arguments = "/s /v /qn /min";
            psi.CreateNoWindow = true;
            psi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            psi.FileName = desktopPath + "\\" + "setup.exe";
            psi.UseShellExecute = false;
            Process.Start(psi);
            this.Visible = false;

        }
```

I want to run the `setup.exe` with `installer.ini` file .

Comment: I'm not at all clear on what you're trying to do - do you have some other program/pair of programs that follow the same pattern, that you're using as an example? If so, can you name the examples? If not, possibly no-one else does it because it doesn't work (well).

Comment: i edited my post. But I can't understand what means "/s /v/ qn/ min ".

Answer (score 0):

you will need to start a process on install button click event. which will call your exe file

```
Process.Start("location of your setup file");
```

Comment: yes, but this just call my exe file, and how I can mention whit who installer.ini to start?

Comment: it depends on your requirement.. on what conditions you want to call those installer.ini file?

Comment: the installer.ini is the inputFile for setup.exe

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9679375/run-an-exe-from-c-sharp-code this link would help you. you can give multiple argument as well.

Comment: You can say me what I suppose to put in place of const string ex1 = "C:\\";
and    const string ex2 = "C:\\Dir";??