# How to make a c#.net app set an existing EXE file to ask for admin permission upon running

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

So i need to create a desktop application that lets me set other exe file to ask for admin permission every time they run..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Execute another EXE from an application with parameters, as admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37592483/execute-another-exe-from-an-application-with-parameters-as-admin)

Answer (score 1):

A small project to reproduce your problem:

1. Create a winform project of asp.netframework.
2. Click the button control to determine whether the program has administrator privileges.
3. When the current user is an administrator, start the application directly. If not an administrator, use the startup object to start the program to ensure that it is run as an administrator.

test code:

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
         public Form1()
        {
             InitializeComponent();
         }
          public void RegisterOpc()
       {
       
        Process.Start("C:\\Program Files\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe");

        MessageBox.Show("success");
       }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            /**
              * When the current user is an administrator, directly start the application
              * If not an administrator, use the startup object to start the program to ensure that it runs as an administrator
              */
            //Get the currently logged in Windows user ID
            System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity identity = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
            System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal principal = new System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal(identity);
            // Determine whether the currently logged in user is an administrator
            if (principal.IsInRole(System.Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator))
            {
                //If it is an administrator, run it directly
                RegisterOpc();//In this method, write what you need to execute with administrator privileges
            }
            else
            {
                //create startup object
                System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
                startInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
                startInfo.WorkingDirectory = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
                startInfo.FileName = Application.ExecutablePath;
                //Set the startup action, make sure to run as administrator
                startInfo.Verb = "runas";
                try
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(startInfo);
                }
                catch
                {
                    return;
                }
                //quit
                Application.Exit();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
         }
      }
    }
```

Test Results:

[image]

Hope it helps you.