# OPEN Demo.exe Windows Application(GUI) Using Windows Services

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio

I have OneExec. which name Demo.exe and in this Solution also one Windows Services Which name is **Myservices.exe**

and

I want to open **demo.exe** On **Myservices.exe** start function(start Event- Services Running) and closed on **Myservices.exe** Stop function(Stop event- Service Stop).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run an exe from C# code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9679375/run-an-exe-from-c-sharp-code)

Comment: I also make Both exe From C# code

Comment: Yes, so you only need to find the path of `demo.exe` and use the code shown in my other comment.

Comment: ok Please send me your demo code