# LogParser in C# Job

Tags: c#, logparser

I have written one job in c# to read through iislogs and push the data to DB.
We are reading the logs incrementally but we ran into performance issue.

Our log files had more than 300k of lines and job kept on running.
I installed Log parser and we can push the Data to DB via Logparser very quickly but is there a way by which we can call the logparser from C# Job to push iis logs to DB directly.

Answer (score 1):

You can call LogParser from you code by calling Process.Start()

See [Run an exe from C# code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9679614/3805124)

Comment: You should include the relevant code here, links might be invalid in the future.

Comment: @poulbak the link is referring to stack overflow