# Tfs 2018 upload process template through c#

Tags: c#, tfs, tfs-process-template

I would like to upload a custom process template(zip file) through C# code to TFS I've been searching through the documentation but couldn't really find any proper way or rather any way to do it from pure c# code (I would rather not use power shell script) I use the built-in method that should be uploading the process template but its just won't work!

Thanks in forward!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
IProcessTemplates.AddUpdateTemplate():
name: get it from the ProcessTemplate.xml
description: same
metadata: the OuterXml node of the metadata node
state: "Visible"
zipFileName: I prefer the full path to the zip file.
```

Get the `IProcessTemplates` instance from a `TfsTeamProjectCollection` instance with the `GetService<<T>T>()` method.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible write c# program which execute witadmin.exe in console with needed parameters and upload process configuration file. About witadmin you can find information here: [Import and export process configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/reference/witadmin/witadmin-import-export-process-configuration?toc=/azure/devops/reference/toc.json&bc=/azure/devops/reference/breadcrumb/toc.json&view=tfs-2018). How run witadmin.exe from c# code you can find information here: [Run an exe from C# code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9679375/run-an-exe-from-c-sharp-code)