# Can I run IloOplExec() Cplex function from c# code?

Tags: c#, cplex

I found IloOplExec() function for Cplex on internet. But I can't use it in my C# code? I think it is for Java code. How can I use it in C#? Should I add a library or a class?

Answer (score 2):

if you want to call and executable from C# you could read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9679375/run-an-exe-from-c-sharp-code) in stackoverflow.

IloOplExec helps if you want to call an external executable from OPL.

Now, if what you want to do is call a CPLEX model from C# you have many options:

- use [concert C#](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.10.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/CPLEX/GettingStarted/topics/tutorials/ataglance/dotNET.html) to write your CPLEX model
- call [oplrun.exe](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.10.0/ilog.odms.ide.help/OPL_Studio/refoplrun/topics/oplrun_description.html) with the link I gave in order to call oplrun to execute an OPL model
- rely on the [C# OPL API](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.10.0/ilog.odms.ide.help/OPL_Studio/usroplexamples/topics/opl_examples_interfaces_where.html) to call an OPL model from C#