# Is it Possible to Run a C# project using Another c# project

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

is it possible to run a C# project Already build using another project? there is any way to invoke the c# execution using a c# Code.

In here I need to execute the Already Compile Project inside a another project.

Comment: I think you need to elaborate on this a little. Do you want to call methods in another project which is simply a case of referencing the project and using its methods, or do you want to run an already compiled exe using Process.Start?

Comment: I need to run already compiled exe using another project.

Comment: Sounds like you'd rather would want to refactor to have this common functionality in a lib instead of an exe.

Comment: Possible [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9679375/1997232).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run an exe using Process.Start

```
ProcessStartInfo ps = new ProcessStartInfo("YourExecutable.exe", "any arguments");
ps.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden; // or exclude this line to show it
ps.CreateNoWindow = true; // and this line
ps.UseShellExecute = false;

Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo = ps;

process.Start();
```

There are additional ways to get the output of your process for displaying or logging but that is easily searchable.