# Can you start a .csproj file using C#

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010

I have 2 wpf projects and one is a console which acts as a server.

[image: Screenshot]

If anyone has any solutions or alternatives, I would be grateful.

I need to find a way of running the server or the console app project after a form has been filled or a button has been pressed.

Comment: You can run both applications together right-clicking on the solution and choosing Configure Startup Projects

Comment: That isn't what i want to do though.

Comment: @MichalLigezka please [edit] the question to clarify that. Also it is *extremely unusual* to try to launch CSPOJ from your code as it is not something that can be executed by itself (unlike compiled exe). Please confirm that indeed you want to start csproj (likely opening in VS) and not garden variety "start EXE in C# code on button click" (which has tons of answers on SO already - I've added one from the answer as duplicate).

Comment: (Note that "how to run exe" also answers the question currently asked in the post - `Process.Start` will work with both EXE and CSPROJ just fine)

Answer (score 0):

Your console application is an executable application. For example, in your project, it's something like ChatServer.exe. So you can call it in your code and execute it whenever you want. for example, in the click handler of the form or any event handler that you want, you can run your .exe file.

for more information, you can see this [How can I run an EXE file from my C# code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9679375/how-can-i-run-an-exe-file-from-my-c-sharp-code)